# Unable to install Skype due to "libxss1 not satisfiable" error

Tags: skype, dependencies

I'm in the UAE, so I can not install skype from the software center.
I made my friend upload a deb file and i downloaded it. I ran it with Gdebi package installer and I get the error:

> libxss1 not satisfiable

I tried to install the libxss1:

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libxss1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libxss1' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Skype needs quite a few libs to work. Have you tried `sudo apt-get update`? That usually fixes like the one you're having: "not available, but referred to by another package". Rounding up missing libs can be a real pain sometimes. Good luck!

Comment: I tried that. Didn't work :) !

Comment: Sorry, then. ;( I'm not very good myself at rounding up libraries... I hope you make it, though! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fire up a terminal using Control+Alt+T, then write:

```
sudo dpkg --install /Path/to/libxss1.deb
```

Ignore the errors, then:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then again:

```
sudo dpkg --install /Path/to/skype.deb
```

or if from repo, just:

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

You should be able to install the package.

Comment: $ sudo dpkg --install /Path/to/libxss1.deb

dpkg: error processing /Path/to/libxss1.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /Path/to/libxss1.deb

$ sudo apt-get install -f
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo dpkg --install /Path/to/skype.deb
dpkg: error processing /Path/to/skype.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /Path/to/skype.deb

Comment: looks horrible i'm sorry.

Comment: `/Path/to/libxss1.deb` is the path to your downloaded `libxss1.deb` file :D . download it from http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libxss1

Comment: *facepalm*! Thank you i installed it now. Now i just need to find it :)